# How to disable column toggle for particular column of Datatable when it is hidden?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I am using Datatable plugin for my project. I have enabled colvis feature to help the table export. Now I want to hide few of the columns for a user using below script:

```
 columnDefs : [
  { targets: 1, visible: (department == '6')||(department == '0'),
   "searchable": false,className:'none' }
]
```

It works fine like column is hidden and it's not searchable too. But since I enabled colvis ,  the column name is visible in the list and when user selects hidden column, it will be displayed. Can any one suggest me how could I disable column toggle too ?

also tried specifying the column to exclude colvis but no use.

```
columnDefs : [
  { targets: 1, visible: (department == '6')||(department == '0'),
   "searchable": false,className:'never', responsive: false ,colVis: {
    exclude: [ 1 ]
}},

],
```

and below is my comple te datatable script.

```
 $('#page_effect').fadeIn(2000);
                var table = $('#testTable').DataTable({
                    mark: true,
                    responsive: true,
                   "dom": 'flit',
                    columns: [
                        {className: "group1"},
                        {className: "group2"},
                        {className: "group1"},
                        {className: "group2"},
                        {className: "group2"},
                        {className: "group2"},
                        {className: "group2"},
                        {className: "group2"},
                        {className: "group2"},
                        {className: "group2"},
                        {className: "group2"},
                        {className: "group2"},
                        {className: "group2"},
                        {className: "group2"},
                        {className: "group2"},
                        {className: "group2"},
                        {className: "group2"},
                        {className: "group2"},
                    ],
                    dom: 'Bfrtip',
                    buttons: [{
                            extend: 'collection',
                            text: "More options",
                            buttons: [
                                'pageLength',
                                {
                                    extend: 'copyHtml5',
                                    exportOptions: {
                                        columns:  ':visible'
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    extend: 'excelHtml5',
                                    title: 'Book',
                                    exportOptions: {
                                        columns: ':visible'
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                                    title: 'Book',
                                    exportOptions: {
                                        columns: ':visible'
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    extend: 'print',
                                    title: 'Book',
                                    exportOptions: {
                                        columns: ':visible'
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    extend: 'excel',
                                    title: 'Book',
                                    text: 'Export selected',
                                    exportOptions: {
                                        columns: ':visible',
                                        modifier: {
                                            selected: true
                                        }
                                    }

                                },
                                {
                                    extend: 'columnToggle',
                                    text: 'Toggle Group1',
                                    columns: '.group1'
                                },
                                {
                                    extend: 'columnToggle',
                                    text: 'Toggle Group2',
                                    columns: '.group2'
                                },

                                'colvis',

                            ],
                        }],
                     dom: 'Bfrtip',
                      lengthMenu: [
            [ 10, 25, 50, 250 ],
            [ '10 rows', '25 rows', '50 rows', '250 rows' ]
        ],
        columnDefs : [
  { targets: 1, hidden: (department == '6')||(department == '0'),
   "searchable": false,className:'never', responsive: false ,
   buttons:[
                {
            extend: 'colvis',
            columns: ':gt(0)'
        } ],
},

],
                    scrollY: 300,
                    scrollX: true,
                    scrollCollapse: true,
                    paging: true,
                    fixedColumns: true,
                    select: true,          

                });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify which columns you want to be toggled by colvis.

Check out [the reference on hiding columns](https://datatables.net/reference/button/colvis) and [the reference on selecting columns](https://datatables.net/reference/type/column-selector)

Since you know you want to hide the column with the id 1, you will need to add an extra option to your DataTable

```
colVis: {
    exclude: [ 1 ]
```

### }

Edit:

Try replacing

```
'colvis',
```

by

```
{
    extend: 'colvis',
    columns: ':gt(1)'
},
```

and removing

```
buttons:[{
    extend: 'colvis',
    columns: ':gt(0)'
}],
```

from the bottom part of your code

Comment: Thanks @JiFus. I have tried this as mentioned above . But no use.

Comment: Thanks JiFus!! :D

Comment: @Jcc.Sanabria Glad it helped you 3 years later... :)